# Need help understanding how to convert sql statement to (Linq) or (Linq To SQL)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Hi I need some help coverting this sql statement to Linq, I am very new to Linq and LinqToSql, and this is my weakness, it seems like this is used frequently and I need to wrap my brain around the syntax. The Code is below.

```
select distinct t1.Color from [ProductAttributes] t1 join [Product] t2 on t1.Name = t2.ProductName where t1.ProductID = @productID order by t1.color
```

@productID is the parameter coming into the function, where I am trying to use Linq in MVC.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be like this I guess

```
int myProductID = 1;//or whatever id you want.
MyDataContext mdc = new MyDataContext(CONNECTION_STRING_IF_NEEDED);
//MyDataContext is your datacontext generated by LinqToSql

var result = (from x in mdc.ProductAttributes
             join y in Products on x.Name.equals(y.ProductName)
             where x.ProductID = myProductID
             orderby x.color
             select x.Color).Distinct();
```

Note That Table names might need to be fixed.

Comment: Thanks that helped out alot.